# Able to make isactive = false for such users who are manager of some other users

Tags: apex, dml, configuration, role-hierarchy

I am able to make isactive=false for such users who are manager of some other users.As per salesforce funtionality i should not be able to make isactive=false using DML as it will throw dependency exists exception.Few days back i was getting exception but now i am not getting such dependency exceptions and hence was able to deactivate users.I think there might be some changes in configuration or customization in my salesforce org.How can i find such configuration.

Comment: the doc on this is here- https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_deactivate_considerations.htm&language=en_US  By any chance does this apply? `You can't deactivate a user that’s selected in a custom hierarchy field even if you delete the field. To deactivate a user in a custom hierarchy field, delete and permanently erase the field first.`

Comment: It was data issue.I have left one custom manager field as null so it was not showing dependency.If we have standard manager field ,still there wont be any dependency.We can deactivate user even if it is a manager of some other user.

Comment: Robert - so are you saying the you did in fact have a custom hierarchy field on User?  and for some users it was populated?  You should post an answer with screen shots to explain the solution